# makePersistent for owned one-to-many rs. not working reliably in JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, persistence, jdo, datanucleus

the makePersistent method of the PersistenceManager is not working reliably. one and the same junit-test is working and after a while its failing again?!
i have an object that includes a collection of other objects. that means an 1-n relationship.
my problem is that the junit-test of my classes is failing sometimes because the objects in the collection are not persisted properly. 
i am using usually transactions but the persistanceManager is transaction-optional

i tried checking the objectState after each createObject and commit... 
i figured out that the objects in the collection after a successful commit have no systemId (should be auto-generated) but are in state hollow/persistent-nontransactional.

that means sometimes they are (if they are persisted):

*Comment [systemId=Project(1)/Comment(6), JDO-ObjectState=hollow/persistent-nontransactional]*

and sometimes they are (if they are not persisted and a refach of the parent-object contains an empty collection)
*Comment [systemId=null, JDO-ObjectState=hollow/persistent-nontransactional]*

off course i could check manually if all the stored objects have an systemId but this approach is not nice at all. the commit should just fail!!

i do not understand that it is sometimes working and sometimes not! that means my code should not be wrong and this is a bug...
pls help me out

PS: i can post some code if necessary!

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Ble implements Serializable, JDOObject<Ble> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// NotNull
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key systemId;

// NotNull
@Persistent
private Key parentId;

// NotNull
@Persistent
@Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.parent-pk", value = "true")
private Key projectId;

// NotNull
@Persistent
private String title;

@Persistent
private int position;

@Persistent
private boolean hasChildren;

@Persistent
private BleData requirementData;

@Persistent
private List<Comment> comments;


//getter/setter
}
```

childObject

```
    @PersistenceCapable
public class Comment implements Serializable, JDOObject<Comment> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key systemId;

@Persistent
private String text;

@Persistent
private long createdTimestamp;

//getter//Setter    
}
```

Comment: looking at the log would tell you plenty.

Comment: ok, where i can find the „log“?

Comment: Where did *you* define it to go ? "log4j.properties" would define it.

Comment: thx, i found the log, but its not helping me in any way :(

Comment: the log and method you can find bellow in a new answer

Comment: The log you post is at INFO level (so omits all of the useful stuff at DEBUG level). Use v2.x of the GAE JDO plugin

Comment: i tried to use a nother datanuclues but its not working...."SCHWERWIEGEND: Bundle "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" requires "org.datanucleus" version "3.0.4" but the resolved bundle has version "3.0.4" which is outside the expected range."

Comment: witch libs should i use? i am using this right now: datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar
datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar
datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar this jars are in the lib folder and the jdo is in the classpath and the lib folder
jdo2-api-2.3-eb.jar

Comment: the log config is somehow not working... still just INFO messages! its in the web-inf/classes folder and looking like this   **
log4j.category.DataNucleus.JDO=DEBUG, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Persistence=DEBUG, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Cache=DEBUG, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.MetaData=DEBUG, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.General=DEBUG, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Utility=DEBUG, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Transaction=DEBUG, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Datastore=DEBUG, A1
...**

Comment: v2.x is Googles default install (with SDK 1.7.1) http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/wiki/UpgradingToVersionTwo

Comment: thanks, i recreated the gae project in eclipse (datanucleus-api-jdo-3.0.7.jar/
jdo-api-3.1-SNAPSHOT-20110926.jar...) and now its working i think :) a lot of thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is always to use a new persistanceManager for each transaction. never reuse a pm!!

Answer (score 0):

the Log if i try to add a comment and it’s NOT working

```
05.09.2012 15:02:06 org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager$MetaDataRegisterClassListener registerClass
INFO: Listener found initialisation for persistable class com.Comment
05.09.2012 15:02:06 org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate
INFO: Performing appengine-specific metadata validation for com.Comment
05.09.2012 15:02:06 org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate
INFO: Finished performing appengine-specific metadata validation for com.Comment
Comment [systemId=null, text=testAddCommentToBle - comment , createdTimestamp=1346850126819, JDO-Status=hollow/persistent-nontransactional]
```

the Log if i try to add a comment and it IS working

```
05.09.2012 15:00:25 org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager$MetaDataRegisterClassListener registerClass
INFO: Listener found initialisation for persistable class com.Comment
05.09.2012 15:00:26 org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate
INFO: Performing appengine-specific metadata validation for com.Comment
05.09.2012 15:00:26 org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate
INFO: Finished performing appengine-specific metadata validation for com.Comment
Comment [systemId=Project(1)/Comment(6), text=testAddCommentToBle - comment , createdTimestamp=1346850025996, JDO-Status=hollow/persistent-nontransactional]
```

the add method looks like this.

```
public Boolean addCommentToBle(Key systemKey, Comment comment)
        throws Exception {
    PersistenceManagerFactory PMF = PersistenceUtil.getPersistenceManagerFactory();
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();
    pm.currentTransaction().begin();
    Ble ble= pm.getObjectById(Ble.class, systemKey);
    System.out.println(ble);
    ble.getComments().add(comment);
    pm.makePersistent(ble);
    pm.currentTransaction().commit();
    return true;
}
```